# How can I open "special locations" in Windows, like "Control Panel" from the command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, nvidia-graphics-card, special-locations

If one opens Windows Explorer and then enters "Control Panel" in the location bar, then the Windows Control Panel will start. Similarly, the location string "Control Panel\NVIDIA Control Panel" starts the NVIDIA Control Panel.

Is there a way to access this from the command line? The following does not work:

```
explorer "Control Panel\NVIDIA Control Panel"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just run `control`.

Comment: I think this might be what I'm looking for -- "control nvidia.cpl", but unfortunately, I'm no longer using the Windows machine to verify that this works. Sorry!

Comment: The following also implies that `control nvidia.cpl` might work: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/86339-list-commands-open-control-panel-items-windows-10-a.html

Answer (score 2):

Control Panel items typically have a registered applet name associated with them. You will have to consult the documentation for the third party items or do a search for them.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Control_Panel_applets_%28Windows%29) you can find a list of the more common control panel applet shortcuts. For NVIDIA it lists `nvidia.cpl` to access the nvidia control panel, which I can confirm is working on my Windows 7 system. In at least some systems it is `nvcpl.cpl`. Another handy one to run from the command line is `sysdm.cpl` which brings up the system properties.

Answer (score 2):

This is easier than you can think, you just need to know the correct name of the control panel application.

The control panel applications are typically files with a `.CPL` extension in the Windows directory.

There are far too many of them, and they can vary depending on what is installed.

Wikipedia has [a nice list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Control_Panel_applets_(Windows)) of the official Windows ones and many of the bigger third part applcations.

In order to find them all, you can go to the command prompt and make sure to be in the root of the system drive and type

```
dir *.cpl /s
```

This will list all the control panel files on your machine.

So to run the Nvidia control panel, according to the Wikipedia link, you would type `nvidia.cpl` as long as the location of the file is pathed. (I cannot test this as I only have ATI cards here at the moment)

Comment: Nice one!  I tried it by going to the root drive in the Windows 7 explorer and typing *.cpl in the search box.

Comment: You can skip typing the ".cpl" part by using:

    setx pathext "%pathext%;.CPL"

(Add /M to the end to make the setting apply to all users of the machine. Use "echo %pathext%" to view its value.)

Comment: doesn't work with the nvidia cpl, unfortunately!

Answer (score 0):

If you open up Task Manager and view the processes before running nVidia's control panel you will see the process:

```
nvcplui.exe
```

is the "real" nVidia control panel. It can be found in:

```
"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Control Panel Client\nvcplui.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Powershell v3+ to obtain list of control panel Items and their canonical names:

```
Get-ControlPanelItem
```

And use

```
Show-ControlPanelItem
```

To open Control Panel items.